# MSI installation command works locally, but not over PowerShell Remoting

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I am trying to use `Invoke-Command` to install an MSI on a remote computer. I am creating the session using credentials for a domain admin account, and have verified it connects correctly.

```
# DEBUG: Test that the connection is running as admin. 
$IsAdmin = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {[bool] (net session 2>$null)}
Write-Verbose "Is running as admin: $IsAdmin"

# Now we need to run the MSI install file.
$TempInstallFile = Join-Path -Path $TempDir -ChildPath $InstallFile
$Script = "Start-Process $TempInstallFile -Wait -ArgumentList '/quiet COLLECTORAGENTLIST=`"$CollectorIP`:$CollectorPort`" PORTPOOLRANGES=`"$Ports`" MAXPORTRANGESPERSESSION=""2"" PORTNUMPERALLOC=`"200`" LOGLEVEL=`"3`" SSLMODE=`"2`"'"
Write-Verbose "Installation command: $Script"
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {$Script}
```

The verbose output:

```
VERBOSE: PSSession to RDPServer created
VERBOSE: Is running as admin: True
VERBOSE: Installation command: Start-Process C:\temp\TSAgent_Setup_5.0.0301.msi -Wait -ArgumentList '/quiet COLLECTORAGENTLIST="REMOVED:8002" PORTPOOLRANGES="1024-49151" MAXPORTRANGESPERSESSION="2" PORTNUMPERALLOC="200" LOGLEVEL="3" SSLMODE="2"'
VERBOSE: PSSession to RDPServer closed
```

Nothing happens though. The program is not installed on the remote computer and there are no errors. When I copy the "Installation Command" directly from the output, however, and run it in an admin PowerShell on the remote machine, it installs the program correctly. So there must be some issue with the PowerShell remote session, no? I am fairly new to this, what am I missing here?

Comment: You’re going to have to wait for the process to complete. As soon as the remote connection ends, it tears down the just barely started Msi process. You can confirm this by using enter-pssession instead of invoke command, just don’t exit till it’s done. Also, remote sessions are administrative by default so unless you have custom session configurations you can probably omit that check

Comment: Doug, thank you for your response. I was under the assumption that the -Wait flag would cause the command to wait for completion.

Comment: If I use enter-pssession, I need to run this prior to running the script, because it only works for interactive sessions, correct? Is there a way to bake this into the script itself?

Comment: I didn’t see the -wait. And you don’t want to use enter-pssession in your code, just do it manually to test your script. If it installs properly in that session then we know it should work in invoke-command

Comment: Enter-pssession is like an interactive invoke-command. Use it to test out your remote code, cause you’ll see lots more than in an invoke command

Comment: Try to launch process "msiexec.exe" and put as argument "/i $TempInstallFile /quiet COLLECTORAGENTLIST=...."